No query results for model [App\Models\Spbu] when delete in observer
Create and update are working properly, but when I try to delete, the queue job always return fails. When I check the failed_jobs table, I see an exception
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Models\Spbu]

this is my observer code
class SpbuObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Spbu "created" event.
     */
    public function created(Spbu $spbu): void
    {
        SyncSpbu::dispatch($spbu, 'create');
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Spbu "updated" event.
     */
    public function updated(Spbu $spbu): void
    {
        SyncSpbu::dispatch($spbu, 'update');
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Spbu "deleted" event.
     */
    public function deleted(Spbu $spbu): void
    {
        SyncSpbu::dispatch($spbu, 'delete');
    }


    /**
     * Handle the Spbu "restored" event.
     */
    public function restored(Spbu $spbu): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Spbu "force deleted" event.
     */
    public function forceDeleted(Spbu $spbu): void
    {
        //
    }
}

and this my job code
class SyncSpbu implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    protected $spbu;
    protected $action;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     * @param Spbu $spbu
     * @param string $action (create|update|delete)
     */
    public function __construct(Spbu $spbu, string $action)
    {
        $this->spbu = $spbu;
        $this->action = $action;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $tenants = Tenant::all();

        foreach ($tenants as $tenant) {
            tenancy()->initialize($tenant);

            try {
                switch ($this->action) {
                    case 'create':
                    case 'update':
                        $tenantSpbu = TenantSpbu::updateOrCreate(
                            ['id' => $this->spbu->id],
                            [
                                'id' =>  $this->spbu->id,
                                'nama' => $this->spbu->nama,
                                'alamat' => $this->spbu->alamat,
                                'latitude' => $this->spbu->latitude,
                                'longitude' => $this->spbu->longitude,
                            ]
                        );
                        break;

                    case 'delete':
                        TenantSpbu::find($this->spbu->id)->delete();
                        break;
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                Log::error("Error syncing SPBU to tenant {$tenant->id}: " . $e->getMessage());
            }

            tenancy()->end();
        }
    }
}

I am using multi-tenant Laravel. I want the data in the central domain to be synchronized across all tenants whenever it is updated or created. However, the issue is that when I try to delete data, the queue job fails.

Once your 'deleted' event gets triggered the model is already gone. Hence the model not found error because you are deleting the model and then passing it into the job constructor.
You can solve this by passing the id (assuming the id is the same for all tenants) of your model and retrieving the model in the job itself.
Documentation:

When injecting an Eloquent model into a job, the model is
automatically serialized before being placed on the queue and
re-retrieved from the database when the job is processed. However, if
the model has been deleted while the job was waiting to be processed
by a worker, your job may fail with a ModelNotFoundException.

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#ignoring-missing-models
